# Determining if C.Z. Ede and Kogiku Nagaya were officially married?

Tags: marriage-records, united-kingdom, japan

It is now almost certain that my great-grandfather is CZEde because my genetic information and the descendants of his mother's family is matched.

The relationship between wrote in the past Denmark, in his examined family record that there is a relationship between the Danish All right.

I have requested the records that would show whether CZEde and Kogiku Nagaya were officially married from the GRO.

However, there may be no record.

If so, will there another way to look to find a record of their marriage?

Comment: Is this the same question as [Record of 1890s UK consular marriage in Japan?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9539/record-of-1890s-uk-consular-marriage-in-japan) A marriage registered with the GRO is not any more 'official' than any other. Unless the marriage was registered with the British consulate then record of the marriage would not appear in GRO records. A [family tree](http://zohrabfamily.atwebpages.com/ztbltre3.html) suggests that they were married in 1901 in Japan. I think you need to pursue Japanese records and abandon the hope that you will find a record with the GRO.

Comment: The webmaster and I made this part of fmily tree. The webmaster and I investigated C.Z.Ede and Kogiku. We knew they married in 1890s.The webmaster decided Kogiku was Ede's wife. GRO said there is no record of them.I will investigate Japanese record.