# Do letters of Ryle Holme mention marriage of Cecil Zohrab Ede in Japan?

Tags: marriage-records, japan, 1890s

I have asked about the marriage of Cecil Zohrab Ede previously:

- [Determining if C.Z. Ede and Kogiku Nagaya were officially married?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/determining-if-c-z-ede-and-kogiku-nagaya-were-officially-married)
- [Record of 1890s UK consular marriage in Japan?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9539/record-of-1890s-uk-consular-marriage-in-japan)

I have now found that Cecil was a nephew of Ryle Holme.

Ryle Holme was manager of Kobe Branch of Jardine Matheson, and before his time in Kobe he worked in a company of Thomas Blake Glover of Nagasaki.

I cannot find the record of Cecil's marriage because he and his wife appear not to have registered the marriage.

Is it possible that the record has been left in a letter of Ryle Holme?

I am sorry that my English is poor.

I asked  for Jardine Matheson Archive I can see their archives. So I can see them, but I must go to there. Now I am in London,but I can not go there.
I come to U.K. to study English. I will go to Bournemouth tomorrow.
So I want to know about Ryle Holme except going J.M archive.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that either personal or business letters from Ryle Holme still exist?  If so, could you [edit] this question to include the steps that you have taken to try and locate them, please?

Comment: In 1890s in japan it was difficult to registration of international marriage.Because if a woman married with foreigner, she lost Japanese  Citizenship.My great-grandmother was daughter of samurai,so she could not official marriage.So the records do not exist.

Comment: I am applying for a viewing of the Jardine Matheson Archive. I inventory was seen, business documents there were many.

Comment: Don't forget that any additional information is better added as an [edit] to your question rather than as comments which may or may not be read by potential answerers.