# Seeking image from New York 1860 Federal Census Index?

Tags: census-records, new-york-city, 1860s

In [Interpreting relationships to head of household in 1855 New York State Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7977) I mentioned that:

> Robert [Sellars] is another son who [in 1855] was living in the same Albany ward
>   as Hugh (senior) that I am still looking for in the 1860 census when I
>   think he may have been in New York City

I think that I may have found him in a record from:

> Ancestry.com. New York, Compiled Census and Census Substitutes Index,
>   1790-1890 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations
>   Inc, 1999.

which has these details:

```
Name:   Robert Seeller
State:  NY
County: New York County
Township:   17 W. Nyc District 6
Year:   1860
Record Type:    Federal Population Schedule
Page:   047
Database:   NY 1860 Federal Census Index
```

Is the image from which these details were taken available online anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ultimately references 3 sites with the desired image, 2 with indexes created independently of the database you originally found.

---

Collection [New York, Compiled Census and Census Substitutes Index, 1790-1890](https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=3564) has no images and was created from a variety of sources described in the About.. section.

The specific entry you are asking about, [Robert Seeller](https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=try&db=nycen&h=21663722) includes the necessary information to browse in Ancestry.com's [1860 United States Federal Census](https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=7667)

Name:   Robert Seeller
**State:    NY

County:     New York County

Township:   17 W. Nyc District 6**
Year:   1860
Record Type:    Federal Population Schedule
**Page:     047**
Database:   NY 1860 Federal Census Index

1860 Census - Browse records
State   New York
County  New York
City    [New York Ward 17 District 6](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/7667/4236636_00001?backurl=&ssrc=&backlabel=Return)

[Image 52 (of 124)](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/7667/4236636_00001?backurl=&ssrc=&backlabel=Return#?imageId=4236636_00052) is page 47

Robert, a 40y old Ireland-born contractor is on line 9. There are 11 persons in his household. Ancestry has him indexed as "Robert Seder". I read the surname as "Sealley".

FamilySearch has him indexed as "[Robert Scollen](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MC4Y-V5G)" (Note that image information matches ancestry.com).

Archive.org also has census images, but no index: 
[Volume Reel 0808 - 1860 New York Federal Population Census Schedules - New York City, ward 17, districts 5 and 6](https://archive.org/details/populationschedu808unit)
and [image 52 is again Page 47](https://archive.org/stream/populationschedu808unit#page/n50/mode/1up)

Comment: Many thanks - that does not appear to be my 3rd great grandfather who was a Ship's Carpenter, born in Scotland about 10 years after this man.  I would also have expected to find a wife named Margaret/Maggie and 3-4 children (Hugh, Robert, William and perhaps Margaret) with him.