# Records of joiners in Glasgow and Edinburgh

Tags: 19th-century, scotland, occupation, apprenticeship-records

What was the procedure for becoming a joiner in Glasgow and Edinburgh around 1840? Are there records of qualified joiners?  Was it necessary to have already a relative in the trade to be accepted for training?

Comment: Have you tried the mailing lists and forums for those areas? It's a good question and if we don't have someone with an expert knowledge of the Central Belt of Scotland here, such should be your next port of call. (Pessimist? Me?)

Comment: Possibly related: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/apprenticeship-records-for-ship-carpenters-at-glasgow-scotland-in-first-half-of

Comment: And https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/crafts-and-trades

Answer (score 1):

'Well in Scotland as with England, and the rest of the UK. A person would require to be a Freeman, as the eldest son of a Freeman or else to have become a Freeman, by Marriage to the Eldest daughter of a Freeman or the Widow of Freeman or else by serving an Apprenticeship usual of seven years to a Freeman or the Widow of Freeman in this instance as a Joiner. There may well be lists of Freeman for the period for the required towns and if a link can be found, it is an excellent way to extend back your coverage of the family line required. However this may well be a very costly and time consuming process. I would therefore suggest that you might firstly consider looking into viewing on line copies of www. Kelly's Directory - Wikipedia.'
Next find the the required City Directory and the period required by you. Then in the Directory for the required town. Look at the trade section of the Directory under Joiners for the surname required by you.