# How can I verify a record of burial on Hart Island, New York?

Tags: new-york-city, new-york-state, 1940s, burial-records

I have found a FindAGrave memorial that lists a Nathain Affelder, died December 3, 1944. The memorial  notes that Nathain Affelder was buried on Hart Island. The person who posted the memorial is no longer available to question on sources, and his memorial has been taken over by FindAGrave. I can find no other record of Nathain Affelder in Ancestry.com, FamilySearch, google searches, Hart Island records, etc., and have not been successful in finding documentation of his burial on Hart Island. As far as I can tell, there are no Hart Island burial records for 1944.

Any other ideas besides me visiting Hart Island in person or hiring someone to research Hart Island records for me?

Nathain Affelder is not the Nathan Affelder, who died and is buried in Har Sinai Cemetery in Baltimore.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question is very like https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10687/1006 and it would have been helpful if you had said why that question and the answer didn't help you beyond saying you looked everywhere and couldn't find your person. Did you read the article from NYG&B that I cited in my answer? http://www.genealogicalforensics.com/Genealogical_Forensics/Publications_files/New%20York%20City's%20Potter's%20Field.pdf